# Font Awesome 5 - why aren't icons like bitcoin, facebook, twitter showing?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Is it only me that cannot render bitcoin and facebook icons in version 5.0.8 ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css">
<i class="fa fa-btc"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

Comment: Well, it really doesn't work in 5.0.8. I don't know if using v4 is an option, but in 4.7.0 it works well.

Comment: Not working here. Firefox Dev, Arch Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to use the `brands.css` stylesheet in font-awesome 5.0.8. Additionally, you need to make sure your class names are up to date. Try the snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/brands.css" integrity="sha384-IiIL1/ODJBRTrDTFk/pW8j0DUI5/z9m1KYsTm/RjZTNV8RHLGZXkUDwgRRbbQ+Jh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fab fa-btc"></i>
<i class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i>
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `all.css` stylesheet to include all the styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fab fa-btc"></i>
<i class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load all the icon type as the bitcoin belong to the **brand ones**. As you can see below you can choose pack of icon you want to load: https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css

[image]

You also need to use `fab` not `fa`. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" >
<i class="fab fa-btc"></i>
<i class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can fix the problem for all fontawesome font types in less then 2 mins. Simple replacement of /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/fontawesome.min.css with /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css and also font-awesome/5.13.0/js/fontawesome.min.js with /font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js can fix this issue. https://youtu.be/_GV_pEmLCLU