# DRUPAL 8 ONLY ISSUE !!! Fontawesome using Web Fonts with CSS in drupal 8 twig file not displaying icon

Tags: css, twig, font-awesome, drupal-8, webfonts

> **UPDATE:** This question was marked as a duplicate of [Can't see bitcoin's icon in font awesome 5.0.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479641/cant-see-bitcoins-icon-in-font-awesome-5-0-8)
>   but I disagree. I have tried all the suggestions of the other
>   question. They are not working. I am able to make it work in wordpress
>   and other places just not in Drupal 8. I am able to make it work in
>   Drupal 8 using SVG with JavaScript but **NOT** Web Fonts with CSS.

I have spent hours googling for an answer to my problem and have not found a solution. Here it goes...
In Drupal 8 v8.6.1 (just learning) I have copied block--secondarymenu.html.twig file into my theme's template folder and have added a social media menu.

**block--secondarymenu.html.twig:**

```
{% set heading_id = attributes.id ~ '-menu'|clean_id %}
  <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="{{ heading_id }}"{{ attributes.addClass('clearfix')|without('role', 'aria-labelledby') }}>
    {# Label. If not displayed, we still provide it for screen readers. #}
    {% if not configuration.label_display %}
      {% set title_attributes = title_attributes.addClass('visually-hidden') %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ title_prefix }}
    <h2{{ title_attributes.setAttribute('id', heading_id) }}>{{ configuration.label }}</h2>
    {{ title_suffix }}

<ul class="social-nav right">
  <li>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

    {# Menu. #}
    {% block content %}
      {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
  </nav>
```

**theme.libraries.yml:**

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    base:
      css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      css/vendor/bootstrap-theme.min: {}
      css/vendor/fontawesome-all.min.css: {}
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/vendor/popper.min.js: {}
    js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    js/functions.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

I also have the webfonts folder in my theme directory. BUT When I open the page in the browser it is not displaying the icon.

**It does appear to be applying the styles:**

```
.fa-twitter::before {
    content: "\f099";
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa, .fas {
    font-weight: 900;
}
.fa, .far, .fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
.fa, .fab, .fal, .far, .fas {
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

**Here is what it looks like:**

[image: Menu with missing icon]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for the twitter it's `fab` not `fa`

Comment: let me know if it fixes your issue

Comment: The `i`-tag in block-secondary... needs to be changed: `<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>`.  As shown @ https://fontawesome.com/icons/twitter?style=brands

Comment: Yes, thank you all for the correction and pointing out that it is fab not fa. I have tried all the different variations out of desperation was just too lazy to list them all here. fab did not work either. I am able to make it work using SVG with JavaScript but NOT Web Fonts with CSS. I am wondering if it is a Drupal 8 or twig file or both issue.

Comment: Is there any way you could give a link to the non-working site for inspection? (Or a fiddle?)

Comment: Not really, it's a local install of drupal 8 using the windows subsystem for Linux on my work computer running windows 10. I know that this is not helpful at all, sorry.